# Accessing only a subset of anonymous closure arguments

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm having some trouble understanding the usage of anonymous closure arguments. To illustrate I whipped this contrived example up in a playground:

```
typealias SomeClosureType = (
thing0: Float,
thing1: Float,
thing2: Float,
thing3: Float,
thing4: Float,
thing5: Float
) -> Void

class MyClass {

    var someClosure: SomeClosureType!

    init() {
        // This is OK but long
        self.someClosure = { (thing0: Float, thing1: Float, thing2: Float, thing3: Float, thing4: Float, thing5: Float) in self.handleThing0(thing0) }

        // Compiler error: "cannot assign value of type '(Float) -> ()' to type 'SomeClosureType!'"
        self.someClosure = { self.handleThing0($0) }
    }

    func handleThing0(thing0: Float) {
        print("\(thing0)")
    }
}

let myInstance = MyClass()
myInstance.someClosure(thing0: 0, thing1: 1, thing2: 2, thing3: 3, thing4: 4, thing5: 5)
```

So basically when I try to access anonymous closure arguments from within the closure, I get this error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the compiler, it looks like your closure is only handling a single float parameter, because your closure never references the other 5 "things" in any way.  So there is an apparent mismatch and the compiler flags it as an error.

If you reference all 6 input parameters in any valid way, the error will disappear.  For example, although this is not something you should ever write, merely referencing the additional parameters like this will be valid:

```
self.someClosure = { self.handleThing0($0); _ = [$1,$2,$3,$4,$5] }
```

The shortest / best possible way to express what you are going for is:

```
self.someClosure = { thing0, _, _, _, _, _ in self.handleThing0(thing0) }
```

where each `_` represents a value you are ignoring, but the compiler can infer that they would be Float values.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. I think you explained the issue well. I only wish the compiler could be smart enough to allow referencing only a subset of the closure arguments. I wonder if this by design or some sort of technical limitation.

Comment: @JohnScalo  Yeah, I can totally see the case for allowing only a subset of the parameters to be referenced.  On the other hand 1) it means the compiler has to assume you aren't accidentally not handling something important when you should be, and generally it's better for the compiler to flag a possible mistake  2) Swift tends towards very strong types and contracts. So if a developer specifies a closure that is supposed to handle parameter "A" _and_ parameter "B", and you want to use one that only handles "A", it's pretty consistent with Swift's nature to consider that a broken contract.

Comment: @DanielHall, while the behavior is excusable, it's considered a bug by the Swift team.

Comment: @zneak Yeah, I saw your great reference to that mailing list conversation in your answer! Seems inconsistent with the practice everywhere else in Swift to explicitly use `_` to signify values that are being ignored: for example, binding to associated values in enum switch cases. But perhaps those are also compiler deficiencies and not intentional. I still think that essentially passing a `String->()` closure where a  `(String, Int, Dictionary)->()` closure is required, for example, is something the compiler should flag, even if it could be argued that having any subset of matching params works

Comment: I agree that you shouldn't be able to implicitly convert a typed closure value to one that requires fewer parameters. However, `{ $0 }` is a closure literal that takes the type of what it's used for. It's like how the `"a"` literal can be a string or a character depending on how you use it.

Comment: @zneak You make a good point that implicit closure literal parameters aren't bad in the way implicit conversion of typed closure values would be. And that there is precedent for inferring / casting a literal based on where it is being used. I think I would be on board with just using the $n values in a closure literal that I care about, should they find the time to make that fix!

Answer (score 3):

This specific issue comes up periodically on swift-evolution. Chris Lattner said that [this is considered a bug in the compiler, but it requires significant effort to fix](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.swift.evolution/17196/):

> On May 13, 2016, at 9:16 AM, Joe Groff via swift-evolution
>    swift.org> wrote:
>
> > > This encourages the use of empty closures over optional closures, which I think is open for debate. In general I try to avoid optionals
> > >       when they can be precisely replaced with a non-optional value.
> > >       Furthermore, most Cocoa completion handlers are not optional.
> > >
> > > The alternative is to not do this, but encourage that any closure that could reasonably be empty should in fact be optional. I would
> > >       then want Cocoa functions with void-returning closures to be imported
> > >       as optionals to avoid "{ _ in }".
> >
> > +1. In general, I think we should allow implicit arguments, without requiring the closure to use all the implicit $n variables like we do
> >     today. These should all be valid:
> >
> > `let _: () -> () = {}`
> >     `let _: (Int) -> () = {}`
> >     `let _: (Int, Int) -> Int = { 5 }`
> >     `let _: (Int, Int) -> Int = { $0 }`
> >     `let _: (Int, Int) -> Int = { $1 }`
>
> I agree, but I consider this to be an obvious bug in the compiler.  I
>   don’t think it requires a proposal.
>
> Unfortunately it is non-trivial to fix…
>
> -Chris

Until the fix happens, you're stuck with the first form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do here, but I'll give it a go at trying to offer some info. With the top one (the long one), that's actually correct. So closures are just functions really, designed to be more compact as little blocks of code within your current scope. If you only intended on using the thing0 property, then you can simply ignore the rest using _, for example:

```
self.someClosure = { thing0, _ in
   self.handleThing0(thing0)
}
```

Though you need to be careful when using closures as its really easy to start getting retain cycles, due to ARC and such.

Comment: An underscore doesn't ignore the rest of the arguments, just one, so you'll need an underscore for each ignored arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In your second closure you use only `$0` so the compiler assume your anonymous closure takes only one argument, taking into consideration the signature of `handleThing0()`, `(Float) -> ()`, the compiler then knows that the signature of the closure is `(Float) -> ()` as `$0` is passed to `handleThing0()` which doesn't return anything.

You then try to assign your `(Float) -> ()` closure to a property whose type is `(Float, Float, Float, Float, Float, Float) -> Void` which is impossible as the closure take 5 argument less than requested, hence the error.